# How to use QComboBox selection in function

Tags: python, pyqt

I have following code using pyqt, which displays two QComboBox's and I want to use the selection values in my applications:

```
class TACRG(QtGui.QMainWindow, design.Ui_MainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(TACRG, self).__init__(parent)
        self.setupUi(self)

        self.CList.addItems(["A", "B", "C", "D"])
        self.connect(self.CList, QtCore.SIGNAL('activated(QString)'), self.c_chosen)

        self.RList.addItems(["Q1", "Q2", "Q3", "Annual"])
        self.connect(self.RList, QtCore.SIGNAL('activated(QString)'), self.r_chosen)

    def r_chosen(self, text):
        report_start, report_end = report_period(text)

    def c_chosen(self, text):
        accs = get_ucs(text)

def report_period(r_period):
    year=date.today().year
    if r_period == 'Q1':
        return (str(year)+'0101',str(year)+'0331')
    elif r_period == 'Q2':
        return (str(year)+'0401',str(year)+'0630')
    elif r_period == 'Q3':
        return (str(year)+'0701',str(year)+'0930')
    elif r_period == 'Annual':
        return (str(year-1)+'0101',str(year-1)+'1231')

def get_ucs(c_name):
    """DO something""
    return """some string"""
```

Now I wan't to use the values returned from the report_period and get_ucs functions (report_start, report_end, accs) in another funtion, which must be called after these two executed. 
How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Store values in class data members using `self`, call your `other_method` in both `r_chosen` and `c_chosen` and check for valid values in `other_method` before use.

```
class TACRG(QtGui.QMainWindow, design.Ui_MainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        # Your init code
        self.report_start, self.report_end, self.accs = [None] * 3

    def r_chosen(self, text):
        self.report_start, self.report_end = report_period(text)
        self.other_method()

    def c_chosen(self, text):
        self.accs = get_ucs(text)
        self.other_method()

    def other_method(self):
        #validate if your fields have valid values
        if self.report_start and self.report_end and self.accs:
            print self.report_start, self.report_end, self.accs
```

Edit (Other method outside class):

```
class TACRG(QtGui.QMainWindow, design.Ui_MainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        # Your init code
        self.report_start, self.report_end, self.accs = [None] * 3

    def r_chosen(self, text):
        self.report_start, self.report_end = report_period(text)
        other_method(self.report_start, self.report_end, self.accs)

    def c_chosen(self, text):
        self.accs = get_ucs(text)
        other_method(self.report_start, self.report_end, self.accs)

def other_method(report_start, report_end, accs):
    #validate if your fields have valid values
    if report_start and report_end and accs:
        print report_start, report_end, accs
```

Comment: thanks a lot!, this seems to work, but raise an error if i just change one droplist, just before changing the second:
AttributeError: 'TACRG' object has no attribute 'report_start'

Can this be ignored?

Comment: And still the other_method is part of the class. What if I want this function be outside the class?

Comment: about  `AttributeError`: Did you put `self.report_start, self.report_end, self.accs = [None] * 3` in __init__? I have that in my code above.